# Open url and submitted data to app in flutter

Tags: flutter

I have a requirement ,in app I need to navigate the user to webview (website) and there will be a form with 5 fields and once the form is submitted a flag to be passed to app and app should work based on the flag .. So how it can be achieved

I have checked that there is a url_launcher or webview_flutter but i don know how to redirect the app once the form is submitted in website

Answer (score 0):

I am not entirely sure if I understood the problem. But here is what can be done.

1. Open url in webview.
2. Now you should listen to webview state change. There must be a listener for this. say the listener is `webViewStateChanged` which will give you the state of webview.

Then you can check like

```
  void webViewStateChanged(WebViewStateChanged newState) async {
    if (newState.type != WebViewState.finishLoad ||
        newState.url != desiredURL) {
      return;
    }

    // At this point, you want to return to your app. If you need data from 
    // website, you can do so by accessing cookies of webview. 

    // Now you are back to the app, you can pop/replace the webview whatever
    // is your requirement.
```